How to connect one javascript client to two different websocket servers?
I have a web app that uses a WebSocket client to connect to a single WebSocket server.
How can I have this WebSocket client connect to another WebSocket server at the same time?
I need to receive data from two different sources (2 different WebSocket servers).
ws = new WebSocket(url 1, url 2);


How can have this websocket client connect to another websocket at the same time? You can't. You can only negotiate 1 connection per client instance. If you need to connect to another socket on a different server then you will need to create a new client.


How can I have this WebSocket client connect to another WebSocket server at the same time?

You can't. A WebSocket object can connect to only 1 server at a time. For what you want, you will need to create multiple WebSocket objects, one for each server.

const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws1 = new WebSocket('ws://server1-address');
ws1.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log('Message from server 1:', data);
});

const ws2 = new WebSocket('ws://server2-address');
ws2.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log('Message from server 2:', data);
});

ws1.send('Hello, server 1!');
ws2.send('Hello, server 2!');


Could you please describe what this code does?
